# PLINQ not improving the performance

Tags: c#, linq, plinq

I wrote a LINQ to find out frequencies of unique characters from a text file.I was also transforming my initial result into an object with the help of select.The final result comes out in the form of a List.
Below is the query i have used.

```
charNodes = inputString.GroupBy(ch => ch)
            .Select((ch) => new TNode(ch.Key.ToString(),ch.Count()))
            .ToList<TNode>();
```

I have a quad core machine running and the above query ran in 15ms.But strangely it took more time when i PLINQ'ed the same query.The below one took about 40ms.

```
charNodes = inputString.GroupBy(ch => ch).AsParallel
            .Select((ch) => new TNode(ch.Key.ToString(),ch.Count()))
            .ToList<TNode>();
```

Worst was the case with the next query that took about 83ms

```
charNodes = inputString.AsParallel().GroupBy(ch => ch)
                               .Select((ch) => new TNode(ch.Key.ToString(), ch.Count()))
                               .ToList<TNode>();
```

What is going wrong here?.

Comment: How long is the input string and how did you measure the time?

Comment: i used stopwatch class for measuring.size is 500kb

Comment: @TimSchmelter He seems to be using a `String` as the source, I'm not sure what that has to do with "IO"...

Comment: @Peter: I thought he wanted to read the file(s) parallel. But he might want to read: [Understanding Speedup in PLINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997399.aspx)

Comment: @TimSchmelter He's only showing PLINQ with the `string`; I don't know what he's doing w.r.t the files and whether that's PLINQ too.  But, if he is, that's a good point.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: No its not.i am using linq only after i pulled out the textual info from the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When this type of question comes up the answer is always the same: The PLINQ overhead is higher than the gains.

This happens because the work items are extremely small (grouping by a char, or creating a new object from trivial inputs). It works much better when they are bigger.

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to tell what's going on there strictly based on the code you provided.

TPL uses thread pool threads.  The thread pool starts up with about 10 running threads.  <s>If you need more threads then the thread pool will create new ones about once every second as long as a new thread is needed.  If your loop resulted in more than 10 parallel operations, it would need to spend time spinning up a new thread.</s>**Correction**: the number of threads a parallel loop needs takes away from available threads in the thread pool.  The thread pool tries to keep a minimum number of available threads in that pool, if it notices that threads are taking too long, it will spin up new ones to compensate--which takes resources.  Lots of parts of the framework use the thread pool, so there's all sorts of opportunities that could be stressing the thread pool.  Starting up a thread is fairly expensive.

The other possibly is that if your number of iterations was more than the number of *available* CPUs, a lot of context switching resulted.  Context switching is expensive and impacts the load on the CPUs as well as how fast the OS can switch between threads.

If you provide more detail, like the input data, I can provide more detail in the answer.

Comment: But PLINQ (unlike other parts of TPL) uses a fixed amount of threads, so it won't use more threads than the number of cores.

Comment: @svick  yes, you're correct.  I was thinking about Tasks... but, the threads used by the parallel loop does impact the thread pool.  I've provided detail in my answer.